# What are the ideal jvm parameters for a 4gb server

Tags: tomcat, jvm, jvm-arguments, ubuntu-14.04

I recently started using 4gb-2CPU vps on digitalocean. Planning to run my java game server along with jenkins on Tomcat7.

I know that jvm arguments could be headache if you need a lot of ram. So what is the ideal JAVA_OPTS for me?

I am using these params for now but doubt it is the best configuration

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms128m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
```

Comment: How much memory does your application need?

Comment: Well there is nothing else to run except for jenkins and my server and of course the os (ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: First of all, you need to decide the amount of memory you need to dedicate to other server processes.
Btw, since this is cloud environment, so I think you could use the full 4096 MB for all your user processes, i.e. YOU don't have to reserve/leave some amount of memory for OS.